# launch C# exe without prompting UAC on Windows 7

Tags: c#, windows-7, uac

I have C# executable that I want to launch on Windows 7 without the dialogbox asking for run-as-administrator..  So here is my code inside the program that launches the C# executable named testApp.exe.

```
Process testApp = new Process();
testApp.StartInfo.FileName = "C:\\Program Files\\Common Files\\testApp.exe";
testApp.Start();
```

I also create the minfest for both programs.  app.manifest for testApp.exe and app.manifest for the program that launches testApp.exe, and then I change the following line in both manifest to:

requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"

When I double click on the testApp.exe to run it, testApp.exe program crashes, but when I run it as administrator, it works fine, no crash.  So this behavoir also happens the same when i run the program that launches the testApp.exe, testApp.exe crashes.

I must do something wrong here.  Do I need to change the name of the manifest because I use the default names that are generated by visual studio 2010.

thanks.

Comment: have a look at following link:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7666408/how-to-request-administrator-permissions-when-the-program-starts

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6059615/net-console-app-keeps-crashing

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/227187/uac-need-for-console-application

Comment: thanks for the link.  the post suggested to use requireAdministrator in the manifest but I want the executable to run administrator without the prompting dialogbox.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually you should only be using

> requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false"

only when you want to run as administrator.

Change this to:

> requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"

And you'll be good to go.

Comment: thanks for the respond.  I use asInvoker but it does not solve the issue.  When I comemt out the code that references a third party DLL, it runs fine but when I dont comment out, it crashes.

Comment: That means your third party DLL has to run in elevated mode, so your best option is to run as administrator. Bypassing the UAC prompt without running as administrator is a long complicated process.

Answer (score 0):

Use 
info.Verb = "runas"; // Provides Run as Administrator

Answer (score 0):

my 50 cents,

instead of adding 
`requestedExecutionLevel level="asInvoker" uiAccess="false"` in manifest you can use task scheduler to run almost anything in highest level (Administrator Mode)

source: http://www.liberalcode.com/2014/01/automating-run-as-administrator-from-c.html

although the above post talks about running it remotely, but you can easily change it to run locally.